# Find the minimum value (excluding 0) from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, min, minimum

I have a dictionary titled `date_of_data` based on a CSV file. Within that dictionary is a key (column from the CSV) called `'total_crashes_per_thousand'`.

I had tried the following to return the minimum value but realised that returns 0 which I want to exclude and find the minimum that's not 0 (could be 0.1, etc)

```
min_crash = min(date_of_data.get('total_crashes_per_thousand'))
print(min_crash)
```

I imagine I need some sort of If function but have had no success so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
min_crash=min([x for x in date_of_data.get('total_crashes_per_thousand') if x!=0])
```

Now if you print `min_crash` you will get minimum value excluding `0`

Comment: greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If this answer helped you then try considering accepting this answer **:)**